# Text inside bootstrap alert overflows

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I have a problem with a bootstrap alert. I inject the alert using jquery.
My problem is that when I enter a very long text dynamically the text overflow the alert box.
Here is the relevant code:
[image]

```
$(document).find('#alertmsg').text('Uploaded the following files: 7.PNG,8.PNG,9.PNG,10.PNG,11.PNG,12.PNG,bitBuck.png,bitbucket.png,Capture.PNG,Capture2.PNG,Chrysanthemum.jpg,database.jpg,Desert.jpg,digital.png,digitalOcean.png,Hydrangeas.jpg,instructions.jsp,Jellyfish.jpg,jssmall.png,Koala.jpg,Lighthouse.jpg,mysql.png,Penguins.jpg,Tulips.jpg,1.PNG,3.PNG,5.PNG,6.PNG,');
```

I also created a jsfiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/4wv0su4d/

Interestingly if you replace the text with a different text the problem is solved.

Comment: Please copy + paste your code, and even better, create a `jsFiddle` so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? It overflow the alert box how? Too much text?

Comment: yes exactly when I do: $(document).find('#alertmsg').html(realmsg); It overflow when the text is very long.

Comment: added jsFiddle  in my original question

Comment: It seems that if you take some of the commas the problem disapears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding some spaces solves this issue, so where you create the list of files you uploaded, replace the comme `,` by comma-space `,` and bootstrap will be able to show your alert the way you want it.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wv0su4d/1/

```
 $(document).find('#alertmsg').text('Uploaded the following files: 7.PNG, 8.PNG, 9.PNG, 10.PNG, 11.PNG, 12.PNG, bitBuck.png, bitbucket.png, Capture.PNG, Capture2.PNG, Chrysanthemum.jpg, database.jpg, Desert.jpg, digital.png, digitalOcean.png, Hydrangeas.jpg,  instructions.jsp, Jellyfish.jpg, jssmall.png, Koala.jpg, Lighthouse.jpg, mysql.png, Penguins.jpg, Tulips.jpg, 1.PNG, 3.PNG, 5.PNG, 6.PNG,');
```

Comment: That was exactly what i ended up doing. Tanks